# Создать массив stdclass object

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Есть задача создать несколько одинаковых элементов типа stdClass object.

т.е. хотелось, получить такую конструкцию:

```
        [params] => stdClass Object
            (
                [param] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [count] => 2
                        [type] => sometype1
                    )
                [param] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [count] => 1
                        [type] => sometype2
                    )

            )
```

Но никак не могу понять как её построить. Для одного элемента строю так:

```
$res = new stdClass();
$res->params->param->count = $_GET['count'];
$res->params->param->type = $_GET['type'];
```

Если добавить еще несколько строк описывающих `count` и `type` - то они просто переписывают значения предыдущих элементов.

Задача простая, но я чего-то туплю (

Comment: Дык, а как вы представляете себе объект с двумя свойcтвами с одинаковым названием `param` ?

Comment: Ну, тут больше вопрос, как это видит разработчик того сервиса с которым я по soap должен меняться данными((

Comment: я просто думаю, что так не бывает, как и массива с двумя одинаковыми индексами. договорится, боюсь, не получится

Comment: ну, система съела конструкцию:  [params] => stdClass Object ( [param] => [0](...)[1](...))

Comment: массив, конечно

Comment: Просто ступор головы не давал ей работать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = new stdClass();
$res->params[]->param->count = $_GET['count'];
$res->params[]->param->type = $_GET['type'];
$res->params = (object) $res->params;
```

Может так сработает?

Comment: Сработало. С ручным указанием нумерации в скобочках. Спасибо) заапрувлю как только система разрешит)